# Does ofstream variable.open support predetermined string variables?

Tags: c++, ofstream

My IDE is having issues with the "filename" variable on the last line. Can someone point out to me why?

```
    switch(filename_selection)
    {
        case 1: filename_selection = 1;
        filename = "foo3.sql";
        break;

        case 2: filename_selection = 2;
        filename = "foo2.sql";
        break;

        case 3: filename_selection = 3;
        filename = "foo1.sql";
        break;

        default:
        cout << "Invalid selection." << endl;
        break;
    }
    ofstream File;
    File.open(filename, ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

Comment: *What* issues...? And how is your `filename` defined?

Comment: Also, any specific reason you reassign `filename_selection` to what it already is?

Comment: Rookie mistake, really. Reading into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My crystal ball is a bit cloudy today, but I think I can see something...

`<psychic-powers>`
Your `filename` is declared as `std::string filename;`. Sadly, in C++03, `std::(i|o)fstream` classes didn't have constructors that accept `std::string` variables, only `char const*` ones.

Solution: Pass `filename.c_str()`.
`</psychic-powers>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *filename* is of type *std::string*, then you can't pass it directly to the ofstream constructor: **you need the power of c_str()**

```
switch(filename_selection)
{
  case 1:
    //filename_selection = 1; WHAT IS THIS?
    filename = "foo3.sql";
    break;

  case 2:
    ///filename_selection = 2; ???
    filename = "foo2.sql";
    break;

  case 3:
    ///filename_selection = 3; ???
    filename = "foo1.sql";
    break;

  default:
    cout << "Invalid selection." << endl;
    break;
}
ofstream File;
File.open(filename.c_str(), // <<<
          ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

Also you seem to have misunderstood how to use the [switch statement](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).